# Velocity field of a fluid in a porous pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, field-theory, vectors, vector-fields, convection

Consider the situation of the image:

[image: Fluid flow in a porous pipe]

A fluid is passing through an infinitely long two dimensional pipe, with a hole in it (form L to L+a). Clearly some fluid will be ejected out from that hole.

Now,

1. *Which property (at least mathematical property) of the velocity field (a vector field) will depict such a situation that **a potion of that field will come out from the main stream**?* Or in other words, what will be the exceptional (mathematical) property of the velocity field around the hole that lets the velocity field to leave the main stream and come out?
2. Also what will be the fluid dynamic equation in this case? Particularly what will be that velocity field of the fluid in the vicinity of the pore?

Comment: Is the fluid viscous, and is there also liquid surrounding the pipe?

Comment: The fluid can be taken to be viscous; but there is no liquid surrounding the pipe.

Comment: @SCh Is it gas or vacuum around the pipe?

Comment: Let's consider gas... moreover I want to know a general answer, which can suit for all such possible situations.